# Netplan Indentation Error?

Tags: netplan

With this configuration I'm getting this error:

> Error in network definition:expected mapping (check indentation) `set-name: eth0`.

Why? the indentation of the named item is proper ... isn't it?

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
    match:
      macaddress: 00:11:22:33:44:55
    set-name: eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a desktop installation, you should be using NetworkManager...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

However, to answer your question, just use this... no need for match, macaddress, or set-name...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # make config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply new configuration

`reboot` # verify configuration

Answer (score 0):

You did miss some indentations, the correct syntax is

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      match:
        macaddress: 00:11:22:33:44:55
      set-name: eth0
```

Explanation: `dhcp4`, `match` and `set-name` belong to (or define) `eth0`, and `macadress` belongs to `match`.